# 01830. 00000 - "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select to_date('13/03/17 05:43:29,000000000 PM -05:00DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS') from 
irregularities;
```

How to convert this date to 24-hour format?

Comment: A date doesn't really have a format. Do you want to end up with a string in that format, or a date data type, or indeed a timestamp (with time zone) data type? And does your starting string really have those DD etc. format elements? If not please edit to show the real string, and the expected result.

Comment: That's a timestamp not a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a string to a timestamp with time zone using:

```
select to_timestamp_tz('13/03/17 05:43:29,000000000 PM -05:00',
  'DD/MM/RR HH:MI:SS,FF9 AM TZH:TZM')
from dual;
```

If you only want a date data type then you can cast it:

```
select cast(
  to_timestamp_tz('13/03/17 05:43:29,000000000 PM -05:00',
    'DD/MM/RR HH:MI:SS,FF9 AM TZH:TZM')
  as date)
from dual;
```

If you really only want the string version you can convert it back, which you would usually only do for display:

```
select to_date(
  to_timestamp_tz('13/03/17 05:43:29,000000000 PM -05:00',
    'DD/MM/RR HH:MI:SS,FF9 AM TZH:TZM'),
  'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from dual;
```

If the original string is coming from a table then just replace the text literal with the column name, and `dual` with your table name. Of course, that assumes the column is actually a string. If it is actually already a timestamp and your client is just displaying it in a way you don't like, you only need the`to_char()` part.

Read more about these things in the documentation: [`to_timestamp_tz`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ.html), [format models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html), [`cast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CAST.html) and [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html).